# Как вывести время в разных городах?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Есть скрипт часов и вкладок для разных городов. Сейчас часы показывают московское время во вкладке для этого города. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно вывести время для других городов, и подключить при выборе города/вкладки Cookie? jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.4.1 (http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) к сайту подключен. Спасибо!

```js
var moskowUtc = 3;
var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  let t = new Date(),
    tt = t.getUTCHours() + moskowUtc;
  document.getElementById('tik-tak-moscow').innerHTML = (tt > 24 ? "0" : "") + (tt > 24 ? tt - 24 : tt) + ":" + (t.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + t.getMinutes() + ":" + (t.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' : '') + t.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById('tik-tak-moscow').classList.add("step");
}, 1000);

$(function() {
  $("#tik-tak-tabs").on("click", ".tik-tak-tab", function() {
    var tabs = $("#tik-tak-tabs .tik-tak-tab"),
      cont = $("#tik-tak-tabs .tik-tak-wrp-tab");
    tabs.removeClass("active");
    cont.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    cont.eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
#tik-tak-tabs .tik-tak-select>span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 30px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#tik-tak-tabs .tik-tak-wrp .tik-tak-wrp-tab>i {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#tik-tak-tabs .tik-tak-wrp .tik-tak-wrp-tab {
  display: none;
}

#tik-tak-tabs .tik-tak-wrp .tik-tak-wrp-tab.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tik-tak-tabs">
  <div class="tik-tak-select">
    <span class="tik-tak-tab tik-tak-moscow">Москва</span>
    <span class="tik-tak-tab tik-tak-london">Лондон</span>
    <span class="tik-tak-tab tik-tak-new_york">Нью Йорк</span>
    <span class="tik-tak-tab tik-tak-tokyo">Токио</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tik-tak-wrp">
    <div class="tik-tak-wrp-tab active"><span id="tik-tak-moscow"></span><i>Москва</i></div>
    <div class="tik-tak-wrp-tab"><span id="tik-tak-london"></span><i>Лондон</i></div>
    <div class="tik-tak-wrp-tab"><span id="tik-tak-new_york"></span><i>Нью Йорк</i></div>
    <div class="tik-tak-wrp-tab"><span id="tik-tak-tokyo"></span><i>Токио</i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let timerId = function(city, utcOffset) {
  setInterval(function() {
    let t = new Date(),
      tt = t.getUTCHours() + utcOffset,
      eid = 'tik-tak-' + city;
    document.getElementById(eid).innerHTML = (tt < 10 ? "0" : "") + (tt > 24 ? tt - 24 : tt) + ":" + (t.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + t.getMinutes() + ":" + (t.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' : '') + t.getSeconds();
  }, 1000);
};

$(function() {
  $("#tik-tak-tabs").on("click", ".tik-tak-tab", function() {
    var tabs = $("#tik-tak-tabs .tik-tak-tab"),
      cont = $("#tik-tak-tabs .tik-tak-wrp-tab");
    tabs.removeClass("active");
    cont.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    cont.eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
    return false;
  });
});

document.onload = timerId('moscow', 3); // id="tik-tak-moscow"; utc offset = 3
document.onload = timerId('london', 0);
document.onload = timerId('new_york', -5);
document.onload = timerId('tokyo', 9);

document.onload = function() {
  let aTab = localStorage.getItem('activeSome');
  document.getElementById(aTab).classList.add('active');
};
let tiktak = document.getElementsByClassName('tik-tak-select')[0];
tiktak.addEventListener('click', function() {
  localStorage.setItem('activeSome',event.target.id);
});
```

```css
#tik-tak-tabs .tik-tak-select>span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 30px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#tik-tak-tabs .tik-tak-wrp .tik-tak-wrp-tab>i {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#tik-tak-tabs .tik-tak-wrp .tik-tak-wrp-tab {
  display: none;
}

#tik-tak-tabs .tik-tak-wrp .tik-tak-wrp-tab.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tik-tak-tabs">
  <div class="tik-tak-select">
    <span id="tik-moscow" class="tik-tak-tab">Москва</span>
    <span id="tik-london" class="tik-tak-tab">Лондон</span>
    <span id="tik-new_york" class="tik-tak-tab">Нью Йорк</span>
    <span id="tik-tokyo" class="tik-tak-tab">Токио</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tik-tak-wrp">
    <div class="tik-tak-wrp-tab active"><span id="tik-tak-moscow"></span></div>
    <div class="tik-tak-wrp-tab"><span id="tik-tak-london"></span></div>
    <div class="tik-tak-wrp-tab"><span id="tik-tak-new_york"></span></div>
    <div class="tik-tak-wrp-tab"><span id="tik-tak-tokyo"></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[UTC сдвиги для разных гордов](https://time.is/time_zones)

Comment: @LADYX а зачем куки? Используйте localStorage. Добавил в ответ. Обратите внимание - изменил идентификкаторы табов - из классов выделил уникальные значения и назначил их как id. tthis is the way it should to be